# Orbits and fibres in categorical quotients

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I am reading [these notes](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Embrion/notes_luminy.pdf) about linear algebraic groups and when reading Theorem 1.24, I came up with a question, maybe a trivial one: in point $(v)$ it is only proven the uniqueness of the closed $G$-orbit. How do we make sure that every fibre contains a closed $G$-orbit? Also, how do we prove from there that in every finite group $G$, fibres of $\pi$ coincide with $G$-orbits? Clearly, in this case, $G$-orbits are all closed, so for point $(v)$ every fibre contains a $G$-orbit, but how do we prove that every $G$-orbit contains a fibre?

Comment: I presume that $\pi$ is surjective and $G$-equivariant, right?

Comment: Yes, $\pi$ is surjective. I am not sure about $G$-equivariance though

Comment: Eventually, I figured it may be because $\pi$ is constant on $G$-orbits, by universal property of categorical quotient

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. :)